# String being passed as integer

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Im making an Android application where I have a registration page that saves users to the database. But for some reason the username section keeps being sent as an integer (if I enter a String it will send '0' if enter a number it will send that correct number) but the value is declared as a String???

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername); //This variable here
        final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               final String name = etName.getText().toString();
               final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
               final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
               final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

               Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response){
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                           boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                           if (success){
                               Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                               RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                           }
                           else{
                               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                               builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                       .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                       .create()
                                       .show();
                           }
                       }
                       catch(JSONException E){
                           E.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }

               };
               RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( name,username, email,password,responseListener);
               RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
               queue.add(registerRequest);
           }
        });
```

REQUEST:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "server link";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){

        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

[image: mySQL]

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss",$name, $username, $email, $password );
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I know its likely going to be something really stupid but I've been trying to figure this out for two days now.

Comment: Where is the php?

Comment: Can you show the layout definition for the EditText for username?

Comment: As a first step you should check (debug?) your Android code and see if a proper username is sent, then check (debug?) your backend code and see that it stores a proper username to the database and if it's still okay at that point, then check your database schema. Now all we can do is try to guess where your mistake is. (Well, we can study the Android code, but I don't see how the problem could be there.)

Comment: @eggThe layout definition is the same as the others, but when debugging it see the String anyways so that cant be the problem

Comment: @Markus Kauppinen I debugged it and the correct string is being sent through. The db schema is the same for the other fields.

Comment: @takendarkkI edited the php code in.